# Filter array of objects based on values in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, javascript-objects

I have an array of **strings** like this:

```js
let countries = ["PT", "ES", "FR"];
```

and an array of **objects** that looks like this:

```js
let people = [
               {name: "Tom", country: "ES"}, 
               {name: "Amy", country: "FR"}, 
               {name: "Bee", country: "US"},
               {name: "Ava", country: "PT"},
               {name: "Kim", country: "JP"}
             ];
```

I need a function that receives the **array of countries** and returns an array with only the people that have a matching country to ANY of the countries in the array.

With the arrays above, if I passed them into a function, I want it to return an array with only **Tom**,  **Amy** and **Ava**, because only them are from countries that are present in the countries array. **Bee** and **Kim** are not included.

How can I do this? /: I tried using `.filter` on the array but I could only do it while hardcoding the values of the countries and I can't do that because the array of countries can change. If I pass an empty array, it should just adapt and return an empty array as well.

```js
const matchCriteria (countries) => {
// Can you help me please make such function?
}
```

Comment: **Update**: One liner: `const matchCriteria = countries => people.filter(person => countries.includes(person.country))`

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for pointing that out. almost forgot that

Comment: Yeah... again man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that:

```js
const countries = ["PT", "ES", "FR"],
      people = [
       {name: "Tom", country: "ES"}, 
       {name: "Amy", country: "FR"}, 
       {name: "Bee", country: "US"},
       {name: "Ava", country: "PT"},
       {name: "Kim", country: "JP"}
     ],
     
     
     result = people.filter(({country}) => countries.includes(country))
     
console.log(result)
```